# How can I determine coordinates of vertex of parabola as intersection of a plane and a cone?

Tags: graphics3d, regions, intersection

I want to determine the point I as vertex of the parabola that is the intersection of the plane `plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, myy, 0}, {0, myy, -1}, {1, myy, -3}}];` and the `cone = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];`
My code

```
myy = -3;
myh = 5;
myr = 5;
pA = {0, 0, myr};
pO = {0, 0, 0};
cone = Cone[{pO, pA}, myr];
plane = InfinitePlane[{{0, myy, 0}, {0, myy, -1}, {1, myy, -3}}];
Show[Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone, plane, 
   Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 
     myr + 0.3}], 
   Text[Style["O", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.4}],
   Thick, Dashed, Red, Line[{{pO, pA}}]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`Reduce`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/Reduce%60.html) to find intersection:

```
i = Reduce[{x, y, z} \[Element] cone && {x, y, z} \[Element] 
    plane, {x, y, z}]
p = ParametricPlot3D[{t, -3, 5 - Sqrt[9 + t^2]}, {t, -4, 4}, 
  PlotStyle -> Red]
g = Show[
  Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone, plane, 
    Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 
      myr + 0.3}], 
    Text[Style["O", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.4}],
     Thick, Dashed, Red, Line[{{pO, pA}}]}, Boxed -> False], p]
```

(x == -4 && y == -3 && z == 0) || (-4 < x < 4 && y == -3 &&
0 <= z <= 5 - Sqrt[9 + x^2]) || (x == 4 && y == -3 && z == 0)

The middle solution was plotted:

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Need to contain the intersection line of the bottom of the cone?

```
plot3d = 
  RegionPlot3D[DiscretizeRegion@RegionIntersection[cone, plane], 
   BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Red}, PlotStyle -> None];
Show[plot3d, 
 Graphics3D[{Opacity[0.8], cone, plane, 
   Text[Style["A", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, 
     myr + 0.3}], 
   Text[Style["O", Italic, 14, FontFamily -> "Times"], {0, 0, -0.4}], 
   Thick, Dashed, Red, Line[{{pO, pA}}]}, Boxed -> False]]
```

[image]

Comment: I need to contain the intersection line of the bottom of the cone.